# Pull a set of numbers from array based on results from a previous query and variable

Tags: shell, math, search

I am trying to get this script to search an output for two associated sets of information. The first is an item called HOMO, wherein it is the largest number from a list. That part I have down. Now this number is contained in one of many iterations that are characterized by a specific set of KPOINTS (for the sake of this we can just think of them as coordinates.

the input file is formatted as such:
"""

```
   20   20   20    1
  0.3771797E+02  0.8111539E-09  0.8111539E-09  0.1146494E-08  0.2500000E-15
   1.0000000000000000E-004
  CAR
 unknown system
    184     30    112

  0.1262379E-14  0.1262379E-14  0.1262379E-14  0.6944444E-02
      1        -52.737972   1.000000
      2        -52.737887   1.000000
      3        -52.737557   1.000000
      4        -52.737557   1.000000
      5        -52.737551   1.000000
      6        -52.737551   1.000000
      7        -22.134925   1.000000
      8        -22.134912   1.000000
      9        -22.134705   1.000000
     10        -22.134701   1.000000
     11        -22.112640   1.000000
     12        -22.112640   1.000000
     13        -22.112639   1.000000
     14        -22.112639   1.000000
     15        -22.112491   1.000000
     16        -22.112489   1.000000
     17        -19.754983   1.000000
     18        -19.753265   1.000000
     19        -19.751830   1.000000
     20        -19.750661   1.000000
     21        -13.526690   1.000000
     22        -13.420203   1.000000
     23        -12.985365   1.000000
     24        -12.985365   1.000000
     25        -12.985077   1.000000
     26        -12.981062   1.000000
     27        -12.979421   1.000000
     28        -12.979421   1.000000
     29        -12.969164   1.000000
     30        -12.810605   1.000000
     31        -12.809732   1.000000
     32        -12.807126   1.000000
     33         -9.346640   1.000000
     34         -9.250892   1.000000
     35         -6.615379   1.000000
     36         -6.615127   1.000000
     37         -6.615127   1.000000
     38         -6.576577   1.000000
     39         -6.576577   1.000000
     40         -6.566414   1.000000
     41         -6.566414   1.000000
     42         -6.566289   1.000000
     43         -6.547741   1.000000
     44         -6.547741   1.000000
     45         -6.545170   1.000000
     46         -6.533212   1.000000
     47         -2.977552   1.000000
     48         -2.975764   1.000000
     49         -2.975764   1.000000
     50         -2.894318   1.000000
     51         -2.894318   1.000000
     52         -2.758182   1.000000
     53         -2.608094   1.000000
     54         -2.572804   1.000000
     55         -2.571006   1.000000
     56         -2.568429   1.000000
     57         -2.253087   1.000000
     58         -2.206896   1.000000
     59         -2.093700   1.000000
     60         -2.093700   1.000000
     61         -2.091105   1.000000
     62         -1.972143   1.000000
     63         -1.972143   1.000000
     64         -1.901668   1.000000
     65         -1.274572   1.000000
     66         -1.087658   1.000000
     67         -0.954972   1.000000
     68         -0.954513   1.000000
     69         -0.954513   1.000000
     70         -0.925137   1.000000
     71         -0.925137   1.000000
     72         -0.911577   1.000000
     73         -0.911577   1.000000
     74         -0.807923   1.000000
     75         -0.652942   1.000000
     76         -0.652942   1.000000
     77         -0.652511   1.000000
     78         -0.630497   1.000000
     79         -0.630497   1.000000
     80         -0.496316   1.000000
     81         -0.496316   1.000000
     82         -0.495959   1.000000
     83         -0.446397   1.000000
     84         -0.446397   1.000000
     85         -0.123431   1.000000
     86         -0.108018   1.000000
     87         -0.107024   1.000000
     88         -0.107024   1.000000
     89          0.314924   1.000000
     90          0.319814   1.000000
     91          0.324503   1.000000
     92          0.882973   1.000000
     93          3.217164   0.000000
     94          3.217164   0.000000
     95          3.217665   0.000000
     96          3.648166   0.000000
     97          3.648166   0.000000
     98          3.962324   0.000000
     99          4.589003   0.000000
    100          5.167440   0.000000
    101          5.681350   0.000000
    102          5.682852   0.000000
    103          5.818050   0.000000
    104          6.229804   0.000000
    105          6.230217   0.000000
    106          6.526213   0.000000
    107          6.528022   0.000000
    108          6.528045   0.000000
    109          6.710402   0.000000
    110          6.711094   0.000000
    111          6.722917   0.000000
    112          6.815409   0.000000
```

"""
The first 6 lines are the file heading:
then a blank space.
then a set of numbers at the top of the list represents a coordinates.
then a numbered list of "bands" followed by their energy value in column two and in column three a number representing "filled or unfilled"

The coordinates followed by a long list is one iteration. There will be many iterations through output file. I have a search query that finds line x in each iteration, and takes the energy value from column two in that line. Those numbers from that same line in each iteration are then compared, and the largest value is the one chosen.

this is the file represented by $infi

for $infi2 the file format is such:

```
    Automatically generated mesh
      30
Reciprocal lattice
    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000             1
    0.16666666666667    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000             4
    0.33333333333334    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000             4
    0.50000000000000    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000             2
    0.16666666666667    0.16666666666667    0.00000000000000             4
    0.33333333333334    0.16666666666667    0.00000000000000             8
    0.50000000000000    0.16666666666667    0.00000000000000             4
    0.33333333333334    0.33333333333334    0.00000000000000             4
    0.50000000000000    0.33333333333334    0.00000000000000             4
    0.50000000000000    0.50000000000000    0.00000000000000             1
```

The first 3 lines are a heading,
then it is followed by a table of coordinates in the first 3 columns. The 4th column is data I am not interested in.
the 30 represents the number of coordinates, and they are listed in the same order as the coordinates in the $infi file.

The results should look something like this
The items here: the "1" represents which item in the numbered list contains the highest value. So, the '0.882973' represents the energy in eV at that point.

So then the script goes and searches another file that has the coordinates listed, so I wrote a portionthat searches THAT file and grabs just the coordinates and puts them in an array. What I am trying to accomplish is this. I want to take that "1" and use it to go to that array and grab the XYZ from the 1st set of coordinates. If the output of that first number ends up being "32" I need it to grab the 32nd set of XYZ coordinates. I need it to look like this:

```
1 0.882973
0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000 0.00000000000000
```

However, I am having difficulty getting it to grab a set of three coordinates from my array, which looks like this:

```
    0.000000000000000.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.166666666666670.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.333333333333340.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.166666666666670.166666666666670.00000000000000 0.333333333333340.166666666666670.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.166666666666670.00000000000000 0.333333333333340.333333333333340.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.333333333333340.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.500000000000000.00000000000000 0.000000000000000.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.166666666666670.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.333333333333340.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.166666666666670.166666666666670.25000000000000 0.333333333333340.166666666666670.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.166666666666670.25000000000000 0.333333333333340.333333333333340.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.333333333333340.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.500000000000000.25000000000000 0.000000000000000.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.166666666666670.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.333333333333340.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.166666666666670.166666666666670.50000000000000 0.333333333333340.166666666666670.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.166666666666670.50000000000000 0.333333333333340.333333333333340.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.333333333333340.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.500000000000000.50000000000000
```

Every three numbers is a set of those coordinates. However they are smashed together?

the script to create the the array and then search the array looks like this:

```
#Nab the kpoint associated with the homo of all homos then grap the associated kpoints
homokpoint=`tail -n +4 $infi2 | awk '{print $1 $2 $3}' |head -n "$kpointquantity"`

realhomokpoint=`cut -d'|' -f ($kpointnumber*3-2)-($kpointnumber*3) $homokpoint`

$kpoint quantity is taken from the second row of $infi2, that "30" in this example says the list will be 30 coordinates long. 

The results look like this:
1 0.882973
0.000000000000000.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.166666666666670.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.333333333333340.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.166666666666670.166666666666670.00000000000000 0.333333333333340.166666666666670.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.166666666666670.00000000000000 0.333333333333340.333333333333340.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.333333333333340.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.500000000000000.00000000000000 0.000000000000000.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.166666666666670.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.333333333333340.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.166666666666670.166666666666670.25000000000000 0.333333333333340.166666666666670.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.166666666666670.25000000000000 0.333333333333340.333333333333340.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.333333333333340.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.500000000000000.25000000000000 0.000000000000000.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.166666666666670.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.333333333333340.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.166666666666670.166666666666670.50000000000000 0.333333333333340.166666666666670.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.166666666666670.50000000000000 0.333333333333340.333333333333340.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.333333333333340.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.500000000000000.50000000000000
```

I have tried adjusting perimeters for the array building, it then adds spaces the data correctly, but then it adds items that I am not looking for from a fourth column in the output file.

I am trying to make the search work in a way where it takes the "1" and then it will grab the set of three numbers bases on x*3-2 through x*3 so it grabs the 1st-3rd numbers in the case where x=1. My hope is that it would grab items 4-6 if x=2 and so on. The arithmetic doesn't seem to recognize the variables, how can I format them better?

edit: added question mark.
edit: added input file format

Answer (score 0):

bash arithmetic is done inside `((` .. `))` and results are used by prefixing with `$`:

```
$ a=1
$ b=2
$ (( c = a+b ))
$ echo $(( c * b ))
6
$
```

---

However, if your array is a single line containing space-delimited coordinates as you show, you can extract the nth by just doing:

```
$ cat >coords <<EOD
0.000000000000000.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.166666666666670.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.333333333333340.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.000000000000000.00000000000000 0.166666666666670.166666666666670.00000000000000 0.333333333333340.166666666666670.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.166666666666670.00000000000000 0.333333333333340.333333333333340.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.333333333333340.00000000000000 0.500000000000000.500000000000000.00000000000000 0.000000000000000.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.166666666666670.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.333333333333340.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.000000000000000.25000000000000 0.166666666666670.166666666666670.25000000000000 0.333333333333340.166666666666670.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.166666666666670.25000000000000 0.333333333333340.333333333333340.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.333333333333340.25000000000000 0.500000000000000.500000000000000.25000000000000 0.000000000000000.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.166666666666670.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.333333333333340.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.000000000000000.50000000000000 0.166666666666670.166666666666670.50000000000000 0.333333333333340.166666666666670.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.166666666666670.50000000000000 0.333333333333340.333333333333340.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.333333333333340.50000000000000 0.500000000000000.500000000000000.50000000000000
EOD
$ awk '{print $n}' n=1 coords
0.000000000000000.000000000000000.00000000000000
$ awk '{print $n}' n=2 coords
0.166666666666670.000000000000000.00000000000000
$ awk '{print $n}' n=9 coords
0.500000000000000.333333333333340.00000000000000
```

You can insert spaces with sed:

```
... | sed -nE 's/(.)(.\.)/\1 \2/gp'
```

So:

```
$ awk '{print $n}' n=10 coords | sed -nE 's/(.)(.\.)/\1 \2/gp'
0.50000000000000 0.50000000000000 0.00000000000000
```

---

The question still doesn't provide reproducible input/output but if I have understood the extra description that has been added, it is possible this does what is wanted:

```
awk '
    # process first file
    NR==FNR {
        if ( NR>6 && NF>3 ) iter++

        if ( NF==3 && $1==linex && ( $2>maxval || maxval=="" ) {
            maxiter = iter
            maxval = $2
        }

        next
    }

    # process second file
    maxiter==(FNR-3) {
        print maxiter,maxval
        print $1,$2,$3
        exit
    }
' linex=81 "$infi1" "$infi2"
```

For sample input files:

```
   20   20   20    1
  0.3771797E+02  0.8111539E-09  0.8111539E-09  0.1146494E-08  0.2500000E-15
   1.0000000000000000E-004
  CAR
 unknown system
    184     30    112

  0.1262379E-14  0.1262379E-14  0.1262379E-14  0.6944444E-02
      1        -13.737972   1.000000
      2        -23.737887   1.000000
      3        -33.737557   1.000000
      4        -43.737557   1.000000

  0.2262379E-14  0.1262379E-14  0.1262379E-14  0.6944444E-02
      1        -12.737972   1.000000
      2        -22.737887   1.000000
      3        -32.737557   1.000000
      4        -42.737557   1.000000

  0.3262379E-14  0.1262379E-14  0.1262379E-14  0.6944444E-02
      1        -11.737972   1.000000
      2        -21.737887   1.000000
      3        -31.737557   1.000000
      4        -41.737557   1.000000
```

```
    Automatically generated mesh
      30
Reciprocal lattice
    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000             1
    0.16666666666667    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000             4
    0.33333333333334    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000             4
    0.50000000000000    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000             2
    0.16666666666667    0.16666666666667    0.00000000000000             4
    0.33333333333334    0.16666666666667    0.00000000000000             8
    0.50000000000000    0.16666666666667    0.00000000000000             4
    0.33333333333334    0.33333333333334    0.00000000000000             4
    0.50000000000000    0.33333333333334    0.00000000000000             4
    0.50000000000000    0.50000000000000    0.00000000000000             1
```

and `linex=3`,

this would output:

```
3 -31.737557
0.33333333333334 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000
```

Comment: This looks promising! I will put this to use!

Comment: This is just a band-aid. You can almost certainly do everything in a single awk on the original data, but your question doesn't really provide enough detail of the format of the input files to easily write that.

Comment: If it is possible to do it in a single awk command, I would like to go that route. Is this something you could help me with? I can share output file formats, is this something better done in dms?

Comment: It's all about the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You don't provide sample data for `$infi2` and `$kpointquantity`, for example, so we have no way to reproduce your problem

Comment: I have edited to post to include output file information.